# Decorator or wrapper function to abstract special cases in Python

Tags: python, function, wrapper, python-decorators

I find myself writing a lot of explicit statements like the following:

```
...inside a larger loop over i:

if i == 0:
    y = ... # some value specifically for i = 0
    x[i] = func(y, z)
elif i == iMax:
    y = ... # some value specifically for i = iMax
    x[i] = func(y, z)
else:
    x[i] = func(y, z)
    #'z' some other input that does not depend on i to generalize the example
```

There seems like there should be a more abstract or pythonic way to implement this construct, beyond the trivial answer of writing another function:

```
def new_func(i, y, z):
    #--- get y based on i
    x = func(y, z)
return x
```

While this may be a style question, I keep seeing this paradigm with different 'func', so I am thinking there is decorator or wrapper solution to streamline this that accepts various functions 'func', but I just haven't worked my way through it and thought community feedback would be helpful - thoughts?

Clarification / Expansion:
Following solution only solve the simple case:

```
if i == 0:
    y = 0 #...some value
elif i == iMax:
    y = 1 #... some other value
else:
    y = 0.5 #... some non-limiting value
x = func(y, z)
```

I am looking at the next level of abstraction. Here is simple example where you would be interpolating within a 1d array to get a value 'z', used to evaluate another function 'func2' to produce 'y' and then compute a new 'x' through original function 'func'

```
if i == 0:
    y = func2(z[i])
elif i == iMax:
    y = func2(z[i-1])
else:
    y = func2(0.5*(z[i-1] + z[i])
x = func(y)
```

Maybe another way to pose the question is "what is a preferred method for nesting functions so that the outer function returns an intermediate value 'y' based on loop index 'i' that is then evaluated by inner function 'func'"?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but couldn't you have a dict that maps `i` to `y` e.g. `y_dict = {i_1: y_1, i_2: y2, i_n: y_n}`?

Comment: So all of it would be reduced down to `x[i] = func(y_dict.get(i, default_value), z)`

Comment: `y=y0 if i==0 else ym if i ==imax else y`

Comment: Actually, yeah, the suggestion by @PM2Ring makes more sense than my suggestion if it's just an `if`/`elif`/`else` case without more possibilities.

Comment: I don't think decorators are helpful here. Maybe use jump tables instead?